# What would a little actor be?

Tags: suffixes, diminutive, agent

I'm trying to make a diminutive of an agent (specifically imperator, to name a prince), and I can't find out how the diminutive suffix -ulus would interact with the agentive -or. My best guess is "imperatollus", following the model of liber -> libellus, but I can't find confirmation, specifically in the form of a diminutive agent of any kind. Is my guess good, or is there some interaction I'm unaware of?

Comment: Nouns whose stem ends in -r, take **-culus/a/um** for their diminutives. e.g. **uxor** → **uxorcula**, **soror** → **sororcula**, **pater** → **paterculus**, and for agent nouns, I found **amātor** → **amātorculus**

Comment: Does the link answer your question?

Comment: @cmw frankly, yes, and I didn't see it before I posted. I'll keep this up though, to make looking for that one easier. The outside resources I found suggested a completely different pattern, which is why I had trouble